# Stabilizing an object using environmental understanding

Tags: computer-vision, feature-detection, arcore, slam

I'm looking for the best solution for placing and stabilizing an object in a specific place in the world.
I thought about understanding the 3D environment and its feature points in order to get full 3D "scan" of the environment and that way to know where the AR object should be located.

I've tried using ARCore cloud anchors but unfortunately, relying only on just one anchor, at the intersect of the raycast and the plane, does not give me stable object- it appears in different places and isn't kept stabilized, that's why I want to understand how do I use the best 3D scan of the environment I can.

I'm open to hear about other techniques too.

Thank you!